# OpenCV - find or access shape contour not surrounded by bg, only separated by an outline

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, contour

I've been trying to find the contour of a single shape in a very plain background using OpenCV's `findContour` (I'd like to use the C++ syntax). However, it keeps on making its outline a contour and not the shape itself. I'm thinking it's because of the white edge resulted from Canny which doesn't make the shape closed.

[image]

Case A: Shape is by the image's edge
(This is not the actual input image but a simpler input image to illustrate this problem.)

[image] [image]

Case B: Background surrounds the shape

[image] [image]

There are the main functions I used:

```
findContours( grayImage, contours, hierarchy, RETR_LIST,CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
approxPolyDP(Mat(contours.at(largestContourIndex)),poly,3,true);
drawContours(output, contours, largestContourIndex, RGB(250,0,100), -1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
```

EDIT: Skipping edge detection gives the contour I need but I need to have the best contour approximate I can get.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you edited your post after my answer. It would be good if you left a comment on my answer explaining weather it helped, and if not, why the approach wasn't working (i.e. what was happening when you tried)

Comment: I actually have tried your approach before and several others. I was just hesitating to make this question complicated and discouraging to answer. Will soon be making replies and edits. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found the reason why I can't get the shape contour but I found a workaround. After doing erosion and dilation, I basically have to draw a border or a rectangle on the outermost pixels of the input image for the background to surround the shape, ...

```
rectangle(input,Point(0,0),Point(input.cols-1,input.rows-1),Scalar(0,0,0),1,8,0);
```

... hence, letting Canny draw a closed shape outline and giving me the shape contour I want. I am still trying to successfully invert Canny's output like what @dvhamme has suggested but it's still giving me errors. It would be better if somebody points out how to properly get or access the shape contour but thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I reproduced your issue and inverting the canny image does not help. What does work however, is using `threshold()` to segment the object, and then running `findContours()`. The contour detector is apparently really not meant to be used after line detection, but works just fine on a binary segmented image, whether the object touches the edge or not.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I'll keep in mind to try `threshold()` once I get back to this project. I've been doing something like `inRange(src_Mat, min, max, dst_Mat)` and haven't touched that since.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try playing around with **morphology operations**?

If your basic problem is that the contour you're getting is on the outside of the object instead of the inside, and especially if your object are made out of so clear-cut and mostly regular shapes, than morphology might help.

I know OpenCV has implementations of *dilation* and *erosion*, as well as *opening* and *closing* operations. A very simple approach that might work in your situation is just eroding the shape a little bit (maybe 1-2-3 iterations) and then doing exactly what you are doing already. Hopefully, then, you'll get the outer contours of the eroded shape, that should actually be the inner contours of the original shape.

I think OpenCV actually implements even some more complex morphology, but as always, try the simple stuff first :D

Comment: I actually do erosion and then dilation on the input image and use trackbars to control the kernels for each of them. I understand that your approach allows me eliminate the parts of the shape near its edges. But I have to use edge detection first before finding its contours to improve the contour approximated. Doing an edge detection will still give me a black image with an outline. And there will be basically 3 groups of pixels - (1) background, (2) white outline and (3) the shape, which brings me to my main problem - why is group #3 not being enclosed in a contour by OpenCV? TIA

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the contour you are looking for is probably detected, but you are not using it. Instead you are using the largest contour. Try plotting all found contours one by one and see if it's in there.

If it is not, try inverting the canny image and repeating the process.

Comment: That's what I expected but I did try plotting the contours one by one and changing the contour mode and contour methods which are taken as parameters by OpenCV's findContour. I experimented on my initial thresholding but the contours formed would always pool around the outline. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks.